# Noun for adjective "neat"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I need a noun for an adjective "neat" (or "cool") in the slang meaning "terrific". My logic tells me to use "neatness", but dictionaries don't seem to list the slang meaning for it. I don't mind any synonym, as long as it's short and commonly used.

It's intended to be used in a "programming equation": `XAML − XML.verbosity + JSON.neatness`, where verbosity is a property of XML, and JSON language is more readable and concise.

Comment: _Neatness_ sounds like a good word for a closet – but not in the way you mean. I think you should provide an example of how you'd use the word; when such words are used as slang for "terrific", they're often used as interjections, so I'm having trouble figuring out why you'd need a noun specifically. Otherwise, I might suggest one a neighbor used to often say (usually slowly, with a tad of awe in his voice): _neat-o frito_.

Comment: I would understand "this is really neat, the neatness of it is high" but it is not something I have seen before

Comment: @J.R. It's intended to be used in a "programming equation": `XAML − XML.verbosity + JSON.neatness`, where verbosity is a property of XML, and JSON language is more readable and concise. :)

Comment: @Athari: you might want to include that information in the question with an edit, as opposed to answering my query in a comment. (As a side note, it looks like that rules out _neat-o frito_). Armed with that new information, however, I might suggest _readability_.

Comment: @Athari Curiosity, what do you get when you remove the verbosity of XML and add back in JSON's consciseness and readability?

Comment: @tanantish `XAML−XML+JSON="JAML"` :D I'm experimenting with an alternative syntax for WPF. Probably it's way too early to think about a tagline for the library, but it doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already got concise and readable, both which work nicely if you want those particular qualities, but an alternative to try capture the "it's rather nicely designed, and thought out, and well, just kind of neat!" might be **elegant** giving you:

> `(XAML − XML.verbosity + JSON.elegance)`

Answer (score 1):

To convey the thought of "neat" as in "that's neat!", these nouns are synonymous, though not all may be still in vogue:

- Hip
- Hiptitude
- Cool
- Awesome
- Far Out
- Groovy
- Gnarly
- Boss